# Unsure of how to interpret the set $\mathbb{R}^X$ where $X$ is a real vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I recently came across the notation $\mathbb{R}^X$ and I'm not exactly sure what it means or how to 'visualize it'. The text it comes from is the following:

> Let $X$ be a real vector space and let $\mathcal{F} \subset
>  \mathbb{R}^X$ be a set of real-valued functionals on $X$.

How come the set of real functionals is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^X$? Is it possible to demonstrate why this is so with some simple example?

Comment: $\mathbb {R}^X=${$f:X\to\mathbb {R}$}.

Comment: It's not totally clear what "functional" means in this context - but I might note also that it is asking that $\mathcal F$ is **a** set of real-valued functionals, not that it is **the** set of real-valued functionals, so the subset relation might express that there is some choice in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'll delete that comment. My bad - got them the wrong way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can visualize $X$ (say, as some set of points) then you can visualize each individual element of $\mathbb{R}^X$ as a real number attached to each element of $X$.

For example, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, which we often think of as real valued sequences $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$, which we can visualize by attaching the real number $x_1$ to the natural number $1$, then attaching the real number $x_2$ to the natural number $2$, and so on.

For another example, suppose $X$ is the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then you can visualize an element of $\mathbb{R}^X$ by attaching a real number to each element of the plane.

Answer (score 5):

By definition $\mathbb R^X$ is the set of all functions $f:X\to\mathbb R$. Again by definition a functional of $X$ is function from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Therefore $\mathbb R^X$ is the set of functionals from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, and $\mathcal F$ is some set of functionals.

Comment: Actually, yes, the definition of a functional on real vector space $X$ is a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{R}^X$ is the set of functionals on $X$. $\mathcal{F}$ is some set of functionals on $X$ and is not necessarily all of $\mathbb{R}^X$, so $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathbb{R}^X$.

Comment: @MichaelLee, yes. You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The notation $B^A$ for sets $A$ and $B$ represent the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.

It is a generalization of the meaning of the notation $X^n:=\overbrace{X\times X\times\cdots\times X}^{n\text{ times}}$ where we can visualize it as the set of functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $X$.

In your case the set of functionals in a vector space $V$ are defined as the  maps such that $V\to \Bbb F$, where $\Bbb F$ is the field of the vector space $V$.

Then clearly any set of functionals on $V$ is contained in $\Bbb F^V$.

Comment: A functional does not have to be linear. Typically, we specify the elements of the dual of a vector space to be "linear functionals."

Comment: @Michael right, I changed a bit the wording.